# Presenting UIViewController from UITableViewCell: addChildViewController unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alertview

I am trying to use the SCLAlertView library to display an alert view when you click on a button in a table view cell. I'm presenting it like this from my tableviewcell.m:

```
- (IBAction)showSuccess:(id)sender {
    SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];

    [alert addButton:@"First Button" target:self selector:@selector(firstButton)];

    [alert addButton:@"Second Button" actionBlock:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"Second button tapped");
    }];

    [alert showSuccess:self title:@"test" subTitle:@"test" closeButtonTitle:@"test" duration:0.0f];
}
```

But when I click on the button the app crashes and gives me this error:

```
[TableViewCell addChildViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126e1bc90
```

It also gives me this warning on the line where I actually show the alert:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'TableViewCell *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'
```

I'm guessing I can't display a View Controller from my Table View Cell, but how could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the parent view controller of the cell as childViewController.

So add a delegate in the cell, attach it in the TableViewController and then call the alert from the TableViewController when triggered from the cell delegate.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Here's how I'm doing it now: first I create a delegate protocol in the table view cell file with this inside: -(void)showAlertView;, then, in the parent view controller I add the delegate in the .h-file, and in the .m-file I write the actual code for the alert view. And then I go back to the table view cell .m-file and the method showAlertView should then only be like: [_delegate showAlertView];. Right? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the delegate to the cell when filling the tableview ? cell.delegate = self in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?